# Can I retrain a TensorFlow lite model on-device, on new data?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am making a Deep Learning Model that has to adapt to the new incoming user data. How can I do this on-device without sending data on a round trip to the server? For example, I make a model to recognize apples and I ship an on-device model using TensorFlow-lite(In an Android Application). Now I want to personalize the model using the Image captured and labeled by the user on-device(Without sending the image and label to the server to train the model on the server and then again tell the user to download the new model). Is this possible?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?